# Where column "c" is not null for each group in column "a" - give group "a" a value of 1

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Column "C" is a flag indicator. I want to run a query where I can sum column "c" where it is not null. I would like 1 value for each group of column A.

For instance group "Test", would have a total of 1. Group chance has a total of 1. Group "Play" has a total of 0.

I would like a total number as a result. Please view my code below.

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| Test | apple |
| Test | orange |
| Test |  |
| Test | apple |
| Chance |  |
| Chance | apple |
| Chance |  |
| Play |  |
| Play |  |

```
SELECT
sum(case when distinct A and C is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a flag per `a` if any `c` has a value, then you can use:

```
select a, (case when count(c) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as has_c
from t
group by a;
```

You can actually simplify this using the `sign()` function:

```
select a, sign(count(c)) as has_c
from t
group by a;
```

If you want this *per row*, then use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(c) over (partition by a) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from t;
```

Obviously, if you just want to count the non-`NULL` values, you would use just `count(c)` without the `case` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you just want 1 if exists:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a,
    1 exsts
FROM
    aux
WHERE
    c IS NOT NULL
```

If you want the actual count of occurrences, use:

```
SELECT
    a,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN
                1
        END
    ) s
FROM
    aux
GROUP BY
    a
```

Comment: To clarify, I want each group in column "A" to have a maximum value of 1 if a value is present. So if there are several values present for the group - the group will be given a total value of 1.